# Problem in Tom M Apostol's Calculus Vol-II book regarding Partial Derivatives.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I've found some difficulties in solving the following problem from Apostol, Calculus Vol-II: p-292

> If $k$ is a positive constant and
>
> $$g(x,t)=\frac{x}{2\sqrt{kt}}$$
>
> let
>
> $$f(x,t)= \int_{0}^{g(x,t)}e^{-u^2}du$$
>
> Show that
>
> $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= e^{-g^2}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$$
>
> and
>
> $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}= e^{-g^2}\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}$$

*In this problem I want to use only the **definitions** of partial derivatives and **basic theorems** on that (as demanded by the exercise).*

**My Solution**

I try to find the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$. So we have

\begin{align}
D_{1}f(x,t) &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h, t)-f(x,t)}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h} \left[\int_{0}^{g(x+h,t)}e^{-u^2}du-\int_{0}^{g(x,t)}e^{-u^2}du \right] \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{g(x,t)}^{g(x+h,t)}e^{-u^2}du \quad \text{(since, for fixed $x$ and $ t$, $g(x,t)$ is increasing)}
\end{align}

Here, I can't figure out this limit. Also, for the other one, we have

$$D_2f(x,t)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{g(x,t+h)}^{g(x,t)}e^{-u^2}du$$

Please help.

Comment: The intuition is that since h is small, the integrand is constant in the range of integration, so you can take it out of the integral (with a value of $u$ somewhere in the interval between $g(x,t)$ and $g(x+h, t)$. The integral can then be evaluated to $g(x+h, t) - g(x, t)$ and when you divide this by h and let h go to 0, you get the partial derivative of g wrt x.

Comment: I see..........

Comment: Can it be done rigorously..?

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh Why can't you use l'Hopitals rule to evaluate the limit in $D_{1} f$? It just becomes an exercise in applying the FTOC.

Comment: I'm talking about applying l'Hopital rule to $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{g(x,t)}^{g(x+h,t)} e^{-u^{2}} du$$

Comment: Ohhh...I misunderstood.. Yes yes I think L'hospital will work here nicely.. Right.. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Chris Custer's answer, consider the general case of
$$f(x,t)=\int_0^{g(x,t)} h(u) \, du$$ Then, using the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= h(g(x,t))\, \frac{\partial g(x,t)}{\partial x}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}= h(g(x,t))\, \frac{\partial g(x,t)}{\partial t}$$ and we can continue for higher derivatives using the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

The two partials are computed by using the fundamental theorem of calculus (FTC), and the chain rule...

Since the upper limit of integration is a function of $x$ and $t$, you need the chain rule...  this means multiplying by $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}$ respectively...

FTC just tells us to replace the variable ($u$) in the integrand with the upper limit of integration ($g$)...

The result follows immediately.